# Splitting List of Names where there Might Be Common Last Name for Two First Names

Tags: python, html, regex, python-2.7

In Python, I'm parsing through a large list of names, something that looks like this:

```
[u' Ron Iervolino, Trish Iervolino, Russ Middleton, and Lisa Middleton ',
 u' Barbara Loughlin, Dr. Gerald Loughlin, and Debbie Gelston ',
 u' Julianne Michelle 
    ... ']
```

I'm able to split these into individual names using this:

```
re.split('(([A-Z]\.?\s?)*([A-Z][a-z]+\.?\s?)+([A-Z]\.?\s?[a-z]*)*)', line)[1::5]
```

For example, if I called this on the first position of the sample data above, it returns:

```
[u'Ron Iervolino', u'Trish Iervolino', u'Russ Middleton', u'Lisa Middleton ']
```

Cool.  This works for a lot of cases.  The issue I'm having is that there are some instances where the names are in the form:

```
[   ...,
 u' Kelly  and Tom Murro ',
    ...]
```

This is referring to both Kelly Murro and Tom Murro.  Any ideas on ways to point me to match this particular case?  I have a function that does the regex operation (calls re.split), so my thought was to add to this function and check if that occurrence exists first.  If there are more than two names in the list, it appears as if the last name is paired with both first names.  This only seems to occur if there are both two (and only two) names in the list and they share a last name.

**EDIT**

I like the simplicity of "alpha bravo" solution. In trying to understand what's happening, I messed around with the Regex101 site demo and had it generate some code.  The code doesn't appear to do anything, and maybe my brain is melting from staring at this for so long.  Any suggestions?

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'([A-Z]\w+\s+[A-Z]\w+)|([A-Z]\w+)(?=\s+and\s+[A-Z]\w+\s+([A-Z]\w+))', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = u"Russ Middleton and Lisa Murro\nRon Iervolino, Trish and Russ Middleton, and Lisa Middleton \nRon Iervolino, Kelly  and Tom Murro\nRon Iervolino, Trish and Russ Middleton and Lisa Middleton "
subst = u"$1$2 $3"

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

The variable `result` is just the substitution string.

Comment: The bulletproof way to deal with this problem would be writing a simple parser.

Answer (score 1):

As a more efficient way for your first match you can use `str.split()` (if your string has been split with `,` ):

```
>>> s=u' Ron Iervolino, Trish Iervolino, Russ Middleton, and Lisa Middleton '
>>> [i.split('and')[1] if i.strip().startswith('and') else i for i in s.split(',')]
[u' Ron Iervolino', u' Trish Iervolino', u' Russ Middleton', u' Lisa Middleton ']
```

and for find the name in `u' Kelly  and Tom Murro '` you can use the following :

```
l=[]
s=u' Ron Iervolino, Trish Iervolino, Russ Middleton, and Lisa Middleton ,Kelly  and Tom Murro'
import re
for i in s.split(','):
   i=i.strip()
   if i.startswith('and') :
      l.append(i.split('and')[1])
   elif not i.endswith('and') and 'and' in i :
      names=[i for i in re.split(r'and| ',i) if i]
      for t in zip(names[:-1],[names[-1] for i in range(len(names)-1)]):
          l.append(' '.join(t))
   else: 
      l.append(i)

print l
[u'Ron Iervolino', u'Trish Iervolino', u'Russ Middleton', u' Lisa Middleton', u'Kelly  Murro', u'Tom  Murro']
```

When you encounter with strings like `u' Kelly  and Tom Murro '` first you split it to a list of names with `[i for i in re.split(r'and| ',i) if i]` that split the string based on `'and'` , `space` so you will have `[u'Kelly', u'Tom', u'Murro']`. then as you want the following names :

```
u'Kelly  Murro'
u'Tom  Murro'
```

you can create a zip file with repeat the last element and the named from begin of the list to last `names[:-1]` so you will have the following  . **note that this recipe work for longest names like (`Kelly  and Tom and rose and sarah Murro`) :**

```
[(u'Kelly', u'Murro'), (u'Tom', u'Murro')]
```

Answer (score 0):

this should give you an idea, use this pattern first

```
([A-Z]\w+\s+[A-Z]\w+)|([A-Z]\w+)(?=\s+and\s+[A-Z]\w+\s+([A-Z]\w+))
```

and replace w/ `$1$2 $3`
[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/164)

Comment: I really like this for its simplicity, thanks!  Now trying to get the implementation to work.